# Xenial-maas container not running

Tags: maas, lxd

I have installed a xenial-maas container using [this doc](https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/installconfig-lxd-install)

Last step gave an error - something about br0

```
gert@cpru1:~$ sudo lxc list
+-------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
|    NAME     |  STATE  |         IPV4          |                     IPV6                     |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| xenial      | RUNNING | 10.145.139.169 (eth0) | fda3:2af5:686d:981b:216:3eff:fedc:e37 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| xenial-maas | STOPPED |                       |                                              | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------------+---------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
gert@cpru1:~$
```

How do I start it again?

Comment: $ sudo lxc profile show maas
config:
  raw.lxc: |-
    lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 10:237 rwm
    lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
    lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b 7:* rwm
  security.privileged: "true"
description: ""
devices:
  eth0:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
  eth1:
    name: eth1
    nictype: bridged
    parent: virbr3
    type: nic
  loop0:
    path: /dev/loop0
    type: unix-block
  loop1:
    path: /dev/loop1
    type: unix-block
  loop2:
   ... 
   ...
  loop7:
    path: /dev/loop7
    type: unix-block
name: maas

Comment: $ sudo lxc-start -n xenial-maas -d
lxc-start: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 317 Executing '/sbin/init' with no configuration file may crash the host